# trying to remove matching strings from list

Tags: python, nlp

I have two strings one that contains a sentence and another a list of names. Look to the commets in the code to see how they are formatted.

I am trying to go through a column in a database and remove all the names from the sentence.

The sentences appear to be unchanged after calling the function.

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    NAMES = set(f.read().splitlines())
NAMES = [name.lower() for name in NAMES]

def remove_names(df, col, NAMES):
    for idx in range(df.shape[0]):
        print("\r", idx, df.shape[0], idx/df.shape[0], end="\r")
        # your list of texts
        texts=df[col][idx]
        #texts looks like
        #['explain', 'decided', 'make', 'coverage', 'area', 'rubbish', 'online', 'checker', 'correct', 'sky', 'account', 'connection']
        holder_list = []
        for word in texts:
            #NAMES looks like
            # ['pascha', 'lang', 'desaray', 'camielle', 'marquasha', 'trasha', 'shaquila',...
            for name in NAMES:
                if name == word or name == word + "'s":
                    continue
                else:
                    holder_list.append(word)
        df[col][idx] = holder_list.copy()
    return df[col]
df_norm['Full Text'] = remove_names(df_norm, 'Full Text', NAMES)
```

Comment: We don't have the file "name.txt", so we can't run your code. It would help if you hardcoded `NAMES = ['blablabla', 'blablabla', ...]` in the code in your post instead, so that it is easily reproducible. See [mre] for help.

Comment: Also we don't have `df_norm`, which is another reason why we can't run your code.

Comment: Note: To access DataFrame elements using an index you should use: 
`df[col].iloc[idx] = whatever`

Answer (score 0):

I updated your `remove_names` function:

```
def remove_names(df_list, NAMES):
    new_list = [x for x in df_list if x not in NAMES]
    return new_list


df_norm['Full Text'] = df_norm['Full Text'].apply(remove_names, args = ([NAMES]))

print(df_norm)
```

If you want to get rid of the `remove_names` function altogether, you can use a `lambda` function, which updates the column using **one line** of code instead:

```
df_norm['Full Text'] = df_norm['Full Text'].apply(lambda df_list: [x for x in df_list if x not in NAMES])
```

#### Note:

The code above assumes that your `df_norm['Full Text']` column looks something like this:

[image: Full Text]

Answer (score 0):

Since you repeatedly need to test for membership of a word to `NAMES`, you should make `NAMES` a set rather than a list. Testing membership in sets is much faster than testing membership in lists.

You can use [pandas' `apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply a function to every row of a dataframe.

If a row of your dataframe is a list of words, you can implement the function to apply to every row like this:

```py
def remove_names(list_of_words, set_of_names):
    return [word for word in list_of_words if word not in set_of_names]

# TEST:
print( remove_names(['Alice', 'gives', 'Bob', 'an', 'apple'], {'Alice', 'Bob'}) )
# ['gives', 'an', 'apple']
```

If a row of your dataframe is a sentence, i.e. a single string with space-separated words, you can implement the function to apply to every row like this:

```py
def remove_names(sentence, set_of_names):
    return ' '.join(word for word in sentence.split() if word not in set_of_names)

# TEST:
print( remove_names('Alice gives Bob an apple', {'Alice', 'Bob'}) )
# 'gives an apple'
```

And then apply it to a column of the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[47, 28], 'sentence': ['Alice gives Bob an apple', 'An apple is given to Alice']})
df['nonames'] = df['sentence'].apply(remove_names, args=({'Alice', 'Bob'},))

print(df)
#    id                    sentence               nonames
# 0  47    Alice gives Bob an apple        gives an apple
# 1  28  An apple is given to Alice  An apple is given to
```